# Redirection of output from the terminal to a file in unix/linux

Tags: vi

I am facing a slight problem in my project. I have a menu driven program and one of my options is *Display all*, which displays all the entries from a map using a loop. The display is on the terminal and I am not being able to view all the entries because it only shows the last few entries before my prompt comes again. I want the output to be redirected to a file so that I can use more commands and give the user a view accordingly. Please suggest few commands or code.

Comment: When you say "menu driven" what do you mean? Is this a console or graphical program? What command do you use to launch the program? Does it have input/output arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a pipeline when you launch your program to write its output to a file.

```
$ your_program > /tmp/output.txt
```

If the program does other things with the output, such as prompt the user for input, it is likely that it uses the second output channel (the error channel) to show menus, so it is possible that this won't get in the way of normal operation and will only capture dump output.

Additionally, programs such as GNU `screen` and `tmux` come in very handy for this by allowing you to capture and look at the scroll back history from a window and even capture parts of it and log it to a file.

If that doesn't work, tell us more about your program and usage.

Comment: it is console based and i use default ./a.out to execute my program. 
1.....
2.....
3.Display

Comment: Does redirecting as above do the job? What else does your program output? If you wrote the program did you setup interface output on stderr and data output on stdout?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect terminal output to a file using this syntax:

```
program params > fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard output (stdout):

```
command > file
```

or if you want to append:

```
command >> file
```

---

Standard error (stderr):

```
command 2> file
```

or if you want to append:

```
command 2>> file
```